# How to work functionality for all Documents in swing

Tags: java, swing, awt, document, jtextpane

I want work functionality for all opened Documents not current open Document only. I had created one swing application. I was open an Document. The cut, copy, paste and selectAll operations through menuItem work for currently opened documents; not working for the previous opened Documents. Please help me.

Here is my code:

```
public class OpenDemo extends javax.swing.JFrame implements ChangeListener{
JTextPane textPane;
JTextPane lnNum;
JScrollPane scrollPane;
int i=0;
JTextField status;
ArrayList<JTextPane> textPanes=new ArrayList<>();
public OpenDemo() {
    initComponents();
    viewLineNumbers.setSelected(false);
}
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    tp = new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();
    jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
    jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    open = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    cut = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    selectAll = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    viewLineNumbers = new javax.swing.JCheckBoxMenuItem();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jMenu1.setText("File");

    open.setText("Open");
    open.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            openActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jMenu1.add(open);

    cut.setText("Cut");
    cut.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            cutActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jMenu1.add(cut);

    selectAll.setText("SelectAll");
    selectAll.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            selectAllActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jMenu1.add(selectAll);

    viewLineNumbers.setSelected(true);
    viewLineNumbers.setText("ViewLineNumbers");
    viewLineNumbers.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            viewLineNumbersActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jMenu1.add(viewLineNumbers);

    jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);

    setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(tp, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(tp, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 279, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        
private void updateStatus(int linenumber, int columnnumber) {
status.setText("Line: " + linenumber + " Column: " + columnnumber);
}    
private void openActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    FileDialog fd = new FileDialog(OpenDemo.this, "Select File", FileDialog.LOAD);
    fd.show();
    String title;
    String sts;
    File f;
    if (fd.getFile() != null) {
       sts = fd.getDirectory() + fd.getFile();
       title=fd.getFile();
       System.out.println(sts);
       title=fd.getFile();
       BufferedReader br = null;
       StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer("");
       try {
           br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(sts));
           String line;
           try {
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                str.append(line + "\n");
                }
           } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(OpenDemo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
             }
       } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(OpenDemo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }
       String t = str.toString(); 
       final JInternalFrame internalFrame = new JInternalFrame("",true,true);  
       textPane = new JTextPane();
       textPane.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Miriam Fixed", 0, 13));
       internalFrame.add(textPane);
       i++;
       internalFrame.setName("Doc "+i);
       internalFrame.setTitle(title);
       try {
            internalFrame.setSelected(true);
        } catch (PropertyVetoException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(OpenDemo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       }
       textPane.addCaretListener(new CaretListener() {
        @Override
       public void caretUpdate(CaretEvent e) {
          JTextPane editArea = (JTextPane)e.getSource();
          int linenum = 1;
          int columnnum = 1;
           try {
                int caretpos = editArea.getCaretPosition();
                linenum=getLineAtCaret(editArea)-1;
                columnnum=getColumnAtCaret(editArea);
                linenum += 1;
            }
            catch(Exception ex) { }
            updateStatus(linenum, columnnum);
        }
    });
       status=new JTextField();
       status.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
       internalFrame.add(status,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
       tp.add(internalFrame);
       scrollPane=new JScrollPane(textPane);
       tp.setSelectedIndex(i-1);  
       internalFrame.add(scrollPane);
       internalFrame.setVisible(true);   
       textPane.setText(t);
       tp.addChangeListener(this);
       textPanes.add(textPane);
       textPane.setCaretPosition(0);
}     
}                                    

private void cutActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
    textPane.cut();
}                                   

private void selectAllActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    textPane.selectAll();
}                                         

private void viewLineNumbersActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
    AbstractButton button = (AbstractButton) evt.getSource();
                  if(button.isSelected()){
                    lnNum = new JTextPane();
                    lnNum.setEditable(false);
                    lnNum.setSize(50,50);
                    lnNum.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Miriam Fixed", 0, 13));
                    lnNum.setText(getText());
                    textPane.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener(){
                      @Override
                      public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
                      lnNum.setText(getText());
                    }
                   @Override
                   public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
                    lnNum.setText(getText());
                   }
                   @Override
                   public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
                    lnNum.setText(getText());
                   }
                  });
                   scrollPane.getViewport().add(textPane);
                   scrollPane.setRowHeaderView(lnNum); 
                   }
                   else{
                       scrollPane.setRowHeaderView(null);
                   }           
}                                               
public String getText(){
    int caretPosition = textPane.getDocument().getLength();
    javax.swing.text.Element root = textPane.getDocument().getDefaultRootElement();
    String text = "1" + System.getProperty("line.separator");
    for(int i = 2; i <=  root.getElementIndex( caretPosition ) + 1; i++){
        text += i + System.getProperty("line.separator");
    }
    return text;
 }
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(OpenDemo.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(OpenDemo.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(OpenDemo.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(OpenDemo.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new OpenDemo().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JMenuItem cut;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem open;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem selectAll;
private javax.swing.JTabbedPane tp;
private javax.swing.JCheckBoxMenuItem viewLineNumbers;
// End of variables declaration                   

@Override
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent ce) {
    JTabbedPane sourceTabbedPane = (JTabbedPane) ce.getSource();
    int index = sourceTabbedPane.getSelectedIndex();
    try
    {
      textPane =textPanes.get(index);
    }
    catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e1){
    }
}
public int getLineAtCaret(JTextComponent component)
{
    int caretPosition = component.getCaretPosition();
    Element root = component.getDocument().getDefaultRootElement();
    return root.getElementIndex( caretPosition ) + 1;
}
public int getColumnAtCaret(JTextComponent component)
{
    FontMetrics fm = component.getFontMetrics( component.getFont() );
    int characterWidth = fm.stringWidth( "0" );
    int column = 0;
    try
    {
        Rectangle r = component.modelToView( component.getCaretPosition() );
        int width = r.x - component.getInsets().left;
        column = width / characterWidth;
    }
    catch(BadLocationException ble) {}
    return column + 1;
}
```

}

Comment: How e.g. the **Cut** action should work for multiple documents? I can't imagine what should be in the clipboard?

Comment: Have you looked at [internal frames](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html)?

Comment: @Catalina Island,Ha I had shown that but,it's not working.Please help me.

Comment: I don't know a better way to have multiple documents open at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, i managed to answer all your problems, but i needed to create another class which i called 'OInternalFrame', so i will give you both code for those class. Tell me if that's what you were trying to achieve :

OpenDemo :

```
    import java.awt.FileDialog;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.swing.AbstractButton;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
import javax.swing.event.InternalFrameAdapter;
import javax.swing.event.InternalFrameEvent;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.Element;
import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;

public class OpenDemo extends javax.swing.JFrame implements ChangeListener{



private ArrayList<OInternalFrame> frames = new ArrayList<OInternalFrame>();
private OInternalFrame currentFrame;
int i=0;
public OpenDemo() {
    initComponents();
    viewLineNumbers.setSelected(false);
}
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    tp = new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();
    jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
    jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    open = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    cut = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    selectAll = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    viewLineNumbers = new javax.swing.JCheckBoxMenuItem();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jMenu1.setText("File");

    open.setText("Open");
    open.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            openActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jMenu1.add(open);

    cut.setText("Cut");
    cut.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            cutActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jMenu1.add(cut);

    selectAll.setText("SelectAll");
    selectAll.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            selectAllActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jMenu1.add(selectAll);

    viewLineNumbers.setSelected(true);
    viewLineNumbers.setText("ViewLineNumbers");
    viewLineNumbers.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            viewLineNumbersActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jMenu1.add(viewLineNumbers);

    jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);

    setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(tp, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(tp, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 279, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void openActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    FileDialog fd = new FileDialog(OpenDemo.this, "Select File", FileDialog.LOAD);
    fd.show();
    String title;
    String sts;

    if (fd.getFile() != null) {
       sts = fd.getDirectory() + fd.getFile();
       title=fd.getFile();
       System.out.println(sts);
       title=fd.getFile();
       BufferedReader br = null;
       StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer("");
       try {
           br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(sts));
           String line;
           try {
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                str.append(line + "\n");
                }
           } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(OpenDemo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
             }
       } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(OpenDemo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }
       String t = str.toString(); 
       OInternalFrame internalFrame = new OInternalFrame("",true,true);  


       i++;
       internalFrame.setName("Doc "+i);
       internalFrame.setTitle(title);
       try {
            internalFrame.setSelected(true);
        } catch (PropertyVetoException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(OpenDemo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       }


       internalFrame.addInternalFrameListener(new InternalFrameAdapter() {
           @Override
           public void internalFrameClosing(InternalFrameEvent e) {
               i--;

               frames.remove(currentFrame);
               tp.remove(currentFrame);
               for(OInternalFrame frame : frames)
              {
                  int index=frames.indexOf(frame);

                  tp.setTitleAt(index, "Doc "+(index+1));

              }

           }
       });
       tp.add(internalFrame);
       tp.setSelectedIndex(i-1);  



       tp.addChangeListener(this);
       frames.add(internalFrame);
       currentFrame=internalFrame;
       currentFrame.setText(t);
       currentFrame.setVisible(true);
       currentFrame.setLineViewer(viewLineNumbers.isSelected());

}     
}                                    

private void cutActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
    currentFrame.cut();
}                                   

private void selectAllActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    currentFrame.selectAll();
}                                         

private void viewLineNumbersActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
    AbstractButton button = (AbstractButton) evt.getSource();

                      currentFrame.setLineViewer(viewLineNumbers.isSelected());

}                                               
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(OpenDemo.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(OpenDemo.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(OpenDemo.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(OpenDemo.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new OpenDemo().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JMenuItem cut;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem open;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem selectAll;
private javax.swing.JTabbedPane tp;
private javax.swing.JCheckBoxMenuItem viewLineNumbers;
// End of variables declaration                   

@Override
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent ce) {
    JTabbedPane sourceTabbedPane = (JTabbedPane) ce.getSource();
    int index = sourceTabbedPane.getSelectedIndex();
    try
    {
      currentFrame =frames.get(index);
      currentFrame.setLineViewer(viewLineNumbers.isSelected());
    }
    catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e1){
    }
}
public int getLineAtCaret(JTextComponent component)
{
    int caretPosition = component.getCaretPosition();
    Element root = component.getDocument().getDefaultRootElement();
    return root.getElementIndex( caretPosition ) + 1;
}
public int getColumnAtCaret(JTextComponent component)
{
    FontMetrics fm = component.getFontMetrics( component.getFont() );
    int characterWidth = fm.stringWidth( "0" );
    int column = 0;
    try
    {
        Rectangle r = component.modelToView( component.getCaretPosition() );
        int width = r.x - component.getInsets().left;
        column = width / characterWidth;
    }
    catch(BadLocationException ble) {}
    return column + 1;
}
}
```

OInternalFrame :

```
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.event.CaretEvent;
import javax.swing.event.CaretListener;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.Element;
import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;


public class OInternalFrame extends JInternalFrame
{
    private JTextArea textPane;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;
    private JTextPane linePane;
    private JTextField status;
    private DocumentListener listen;
    public OInternalFrame(String title,boolean resizable,boolean closable)
    {
        super(title,resizable,closable);
        initComponents();
        initListeners();
    }
    private void initComponents()
    {

        textPane = new JTextArea();
        linePane = new JTextPane();
        status = new JTextField();
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        textPane.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Miriam Fixed", 0, 13));
        status.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

        linePane.setEditable(false);
        linePane.setSize(50,50);
        linePane.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Miriam Fixed", 0, 13));
        status.setEditable(false);
//        add(textPane);

        add(scrollPane);

        add(status,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        scrollPane.getViewport().add(textPane);
        scrollPane.setRowHeaderView(linePane); 
        setVisible(true);
        linePane.setVisible(false);
        updateStatus(1,1);
        scrollPane.setVisible(true);

    }
    private void initListeners()
    {
        textPane.addCaretListener(new CaretListener() {
            @Override
            public void caretUpdate(CaretEvent e) {

                int linenum = 1;
                int columnnum = 1;
                try {
                    int caretpos = textPane.getCaretPosition();
                    linenum=getLineAtCaret()-1;
                    columnnum=getColumnAtCaret();
                    linenum += 1;
                }
                catch(Exception ex) { }
                updateStatus(linenum, columnnum);
            }
        });
        listen = new DocumentListener(){
            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
            linePane.setText(getText());
          }
         @Override
         public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
          linePane.setText(getText());
         }
         @Override
         public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
          linePane.setText(getText());
         }
        };


         }

    public int getLineAtCaret()
    {   
        int line = 0;
        int caretPosition = textPane.getCaretPosition();


        try {
            line = textPane.getLineOfOffset(caretPosition);

        } catch (BadLocationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return line+1;
    }

    public int getColumnAtCaret()
    {
        FontMetrics fm = textPane.getFontMetrics( textPane.getFont() );
        int characterWidth = fm.stringWidth( "0" );
        int column = 0;
        try
        {
            Rectangle r = textPane.modelToView( textPane.getCaretPosition() );
            int width = r.x - textPane.getInsets().left;
            column = width / characterWidth;
        }
        catch(BadLocationException ble) {}
        return column + 1;
    }

    private void updateStatus(int linenumber, int columnnumber) 
    {
        status.setText("Line: " + linenumber + " Column: " + columnnumber);
    }    


    public void setText(String t)
    {
        System.out.println(t);

        textPane.setText(t);

        textPane.setCaretPosition(0);
        textPane.setVisible(true);
        textPane.repaint();
    }
    public void setLineViewer(boolean enabled)
    {
        if(enabled)
        {
        linePane.setText(getText());
        linePane.setCaretPosition(0);
        linePane.revalidate();
        linePane.repaint();

        textPane.getDocument().addDocumentListener(listen);
        }
        else
        {
            linePane.setText("");
            textPane.getDocument().removeDocumentListener(listen);
        }


        linePane.setVisible(enabled);
    }
    public void cut()
    {
        textPane.cut();
    }
    public void selectAll()
    {
        textPane.selectAll();
    }
    public String getText(){
        int caretPosition = textPane.getLineCount();

        String text = "1" + System.getProperty("line.separator");
        for(int i = 2; i <=  caretPosition-1; i++){
            text += i + System.getProperty("line.separator");
        }
        return text;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Actions provided by the `DefaultEditorKit`. For example:

```
JMenuItem cut = new DefaultEditorKit.CutAction();
```

For a "SelectAll" Action you will need to create your own by extending `TextAction`:

```
class SelectAll extends TextAction
{
    public SelectAll()
    {
        super("Select All");
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        JTextComponent component = getFocusedComponent();
        component.selectAll();
    }
}
```

These Actions will work on the last text component that had focus.

Comment: @user3709795, I did give you the code. Its one line of code to create the `Cut Action`. Then you add the menu item to your menu. I don't know what other code you need. The code works fine if you use the default Actions. You need to get rid of all you old code. This is approach is far easier to implement and maintain. There is no need to manage the "currentTextPane" since this is handled by the `TextAction` class. Don't reinvent the wheel!

Comment: I am developing this project using NetBeans IDE.Design was Developed by using IDE only.The code generated by IDE is not editable.So,when I am creating the menuitem I cann't change the code.Thank you for reply and how can I change it.

Comment: I don't use an IDE so I don't know how the IDE works. I spend my time learning Java, not learning an IDE because then the code is not portable if you ever move to another IDE. You can always use the `setAction(...)` method of a JMenuItem.